# I want to use wordpress database in android app using json encode?

Tags: php, database, json

I want to use wordpress database in android app using json encode, but due to encryption used in wordpress i'm unable to use that, anybody know any solution?

Comment: are you using https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/ plugin to get data ?

Comment: no, I'm using normal PHP page to generate PHP API. @GovindKumar It's working but main problem is encryption used in wordpress.

Comment: ok, so what exact error you fetching ?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by encryption? The link above gives you a very good solution actually to most of the common problems with API generation. (actually i mean https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/ )

Comment: in WordPress website, encryption is used to store a password in the database, and I don't know that encryption code. Now to use that database in android app I have to use that encryption code to encrypt password so that it match password in database.

Comment: Let me check that plugin. @websupporter

Comment: i think it would be the best to go with the official API and use their authentication system (http://v2.wp-api.org/). Otherwise have a look into https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

Comment: Why can't you use `wp_check_password()` function?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other its recommended to use rest-api or else you can write your own class to output required data as JSON